# Java priority queue peek and poll

Tags: java, user-interface, priority-queue

I am trying to make a table model with data inside a priority queue.
The problem is - that when I write "peek" obviously it retrieves always the top of the queue,
but when I write "poll" the table doesn't show any data at all and I don't understand why,
maybe someone hava an idea?

the data strcture:

```
/**
* date 
*/
    private Queue<Entry<Flight,Double>> data=new PriorityQueue<Entry<Flight,Double>>();
```

the get value at method:

```
  @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if(!data.isEmpty()){
             Entry<Flight,Double> e=data.poll();

             switch(columnIndex)
             {
                case 0:
                    return e.getKey().getFlightNumber();

                case 1:
                    return e.getKey().getFlightDateAndTimeSource();

                case 2:
                    return e.getKey().getFlightDateAndTimeDestination();
                case 3:
                    return e.getKey().getSource();
                case 4:
                    return e.getKey().getDestination();
                case 5:
                    return e.getKey().getFlightCost();
                case 6:
                    return e.getKey().getAirplane();
                case 7:
                    return e.getValue();

                 default: return -1;
             }

        }
        else
            return " ";
    }
```

I checked by debugging and the data is not empty. also it works with peek.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so `e` gets set to `null`?

Comment: You do realize that your queue is going to be emptied **with every render**? Why on earth would you use a queue as a data model anyway?

Comment: I didn't choose the type, it is a given method of this homework that return priority queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a `Queue` in this case is that it is not designed to be traversed more than once. I suggest switching to a sorted `List`. I think what is happening is that it is being drawn once which empties the `Queue` and any subsequent refresh, redraw or redering sees an empty `Queue`

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing the sense of this construct, i'd suggest it may be a about the way you are using the `PriorityQueue`.
Inside `getValueAt` you are able to read from the queue using `peek`, but `poll` tries to modify it, which seems to be the problem. 
Is `getValueAt` in the same class like your `private Queue<Entry<Flight,Double>> data`?

Depending on the way you are accessing/using the queue, it might solve your problem, declaring it as `static`.

It would be very useful if you'd provide little bit more code.

Comment: Yes, it is all in the same class. the class extends AbstractTableModel and all the other methods are standard override. I tried to change the data to a list and to add all the elements of the queue and it works, but I didn't find a solution to it by using the queue.